# Avoiding out of gas errors when making Oraclize queries that have callbacks which trigger more queries

Tags: gas, testrpc, out-of-gas, oracles, gas-limit

I have a contract that I want to automatically check the price of ethereum everyday. right now I have a method called `startContract` which calls a function `setConversion` which makes a query set for 1 day in the future. When the `__callback` method sees the query id created by the check price query it calls `setConversionCb` which in turn calls `setConversion`. The problem I've noticed while running my contract with `Truffle`, `ethereum-bridge` and `testrpc` is that after several queries to `Oraclize` I get an out of gas error in the `ethereum-bridge` console.

See here (contract addresses annonymized):

```
[2017-04-21T01:43:35.879Z] INFO sending __callback tx...
    {"contract_myid":"0xc1f9a50449102fbdbd32ef8cb9c22b623d55480e4474","contract_address":"0x17c89ee345e2521b8eb6e91e576"}
[2017-04-21T01:43:36.969Z] ERROR callback tx error, contract myid: 0xc1f9a50449102fbdbd32ef8cb9c22b8973537dbcf665c0be60623d55480e4474
    {"message":"VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas","stack":"Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas
.
.
.
```

Since there is a gas limit, I feel like this approach would be unsustainable if I plan on making the query every day for upwards of a month. What is the best way of handling this? Ethereum Alarm Clock? Or is there simply a change in my existing logic I can make?

Comment: Hi Denis, Thomas from Oraclize here. The out-of-gas is definitely related to some application specific issue that is not being properly handled. In order to help you further, I would need to see your specific code though, can you maybe provide it (at least the relevant parts as the full __callback method code and the exact oraclize_query that you are sending)?

Comment: What makes you say that? The reason Im asking is because I was able to to avoid the error for a significantly long time by increasing the gas limit in the query call.

Comment: Well, it is just my best guess, without seeing the code (with just the info you have provided) that's all I (and anybody else) can do. I would be happy to help once more details (like the callback code and the query, at the very least) are provided. Thanks!

Comment: Also, the callback tx is what gets called so the error cannot really be anywhere else (assumining that the Oraclize callback tx.data is not malformed, which based on our experience, public txs and the feedback we get, it never happened in the last 2 years).